# Convert int labels to one_hot encoding (categorical) in ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am looking for a simple way to convert integer labels to one-hot encoded labels using `ImageDataGenerator` wrapper. I find it very weird that this does not exist in `keras` as default. [Documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) says:

> if class_mode is "categorical" (default value) it must include the y_col column with the class/es of each image. Values in column can be string/list/tuple if a single class or list/tuple if multiple classes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2

cv2.imwrite('temp.png',np.random.rand(3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame({'img_path':['./temp.png','./temp.png','./temp.png','./temp.png'],'label':[0,1,2,3]})


image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator({})

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df,
            x_col="img_path",
            y_col="label",
            class_mode="categorical",
            batch_size=1
            )
```

As expected, this returns

```
TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="label" column values must be type string, list or tuple.
```

I might create one-hot encoded labels by myself (which I still find it very stupid),  but it does not work either.

```
df['label_one_hot_encoded']= df.apply(lambda row: np.eye(4)[row['label']].tolist(),axis=1)
```

```
     img_path  label label_one_hot_encoded
0  ./temp.png      0  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1  ./temp.png      1  [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2  ./temp.png      2  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
3  ./temp.png      3  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

```
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df,
            x_col="img_path",
            y_col="label_one_hot_encoded",
            class_mode="categorical",
            batch_size=1
            )
```

This returns,

```
Found 4 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
```

There are supposed to be 4 classes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `temp.png` even exist?

Comment: I create it with the line `np.save(file='temp.png'...` just to be able to use `flow_from_dataframe`.

Comment: I'm not familar with `np.save` to save images. Does it create a valid `png` that you can open? Try `plt.imsave`

Comment: Feel free to change that line with `import cv2   cv2.imwrite('temp.png', np.random.rand(3,3))`. Or any other method to save an image. The error from `keras` will remain.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem. As the documentation says, `class_mode` does not accept any integer labels, but strings, and the label indices are alphanumeric. So, if I assign a letter for each integer label in the alphabetic order (e.g. 0: 'a', 1: 'b' etc.), I will have the one-hot encoding for each label.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2
import string


letters = string.ascii_lowercase

cv2.imwrite('temp.png',np.random.rand(3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame({'img_path':['./temp.png','./temp.png','./temp.png','./temp.png'],'label':[0,1,2,3]})


df['label_letters'] = df.apply(lambda row: letters[row['label']],axis=1)

print(df.head())
```

```
     img_path  label label_letters
0  ./temp.png      0             a
1  ./temp.png      1             b
2  ./temp.png      2             c
3  ./temp.png      3             d
```

```
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator({})

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df,
            x_col="img_path",
            y_col="label_letters",
            class_mode="categorical",
            batch_size=4,
            shuffle=False
            )

x,y=next(image_generator)

print(y)
```

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Ta-da! I am sure there is a more proper way to achieve this, but this works anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the directory, or give Keras absolute paths. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe):

> **directory:**    string, path to the directory to read images from. If None, data in x_col column should be absolute paths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right about using `numpy` to save images, it was my bad. I fixed that. But I do not have any problem with the file path, either `temp.png` or `./temp.png` works fine (I edited my answer as absolute paths just to make it clear for you). My current problem is `keras` somehow returns binary classes from one-hot encoded lists.